# Different behavior of regex in IE and chrome with white spaces

Tags: javascript, sapui5

I got the following function which checks what the input is:

```
validateInputFields: function() {
        var bValid = true;
        var oIDNumber = this.getView().byId("iDNumber");
        var regex = /^[0-9]+$/;

        if (oIDNumber.getValue().trim().length === 0 || (oIDNumber.getValue().match(regex) == null)) {
            bValid = false;
            oIDNumber.setValueState(sap.ui.core.ValueState.Error);
        } else {
            oIDNumber.setValueState(sap.ui.core.ValueState.Success);
        }
        return bValid;
    }
```

and I want only numbers without spaces in between to be valid..... the problem is if I call the UI with chrome and I enter spaces nothing happens I can't add space in that input field even if I copy a numeric string with spaces in it and paste it into it chrome just ignores those white spaces while IE doesn't which leads to this inconsistent behavior that one just ignores spaces the other accepts it but then through this check the field will be marked as "not valid entry"...... how can I change this behavior to a similar one

Comment: If you are using UI5 you can use **sap.m.Input** to enter only numbers without any spaces and character except numbers. Here is the [example](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/explored.html#/sample/sap.m.sample.InputTypes/preview)

Comment: thanks I try that out later

Comment: @NaveenKumarHS it is weird because even using `type="Number"` will not change that it is possible to add spaces in IE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So using SAPUI5 there is no way you can get rid of this inconsistency. The following is mentioned in the [API Reference](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.m.Input/methods/setType):

> HTML type of the internal input tag (e.g. Text, Number, Email, Phone). The particular effect of this property differs depending on the browser and the current language settings, especially for the type Number.